# Outlook for web, removing automatic categories/tags for external inbox

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-web-app

This question is about Outlook Web App (OWA), not standalone app.

When you connect OWA to an external account (say: gmail) then all emails coming from this account to OWA are automatically categorised as `sample.email@gmail.com`. 
Small rectangle text box with that address is shown  on each email and it covers email's body preview (which is the main reason why I investigate how to get rid of it).

You may remove that category from categories list, but it doesn't change the fact that the category still exist, the emails are still labeled as `sample.email@gmail.com`, and you may still search `category:"sample.email@gmail.com"` - despite the category is not present in the categories list.

How do I remove this category permanently and make sure that any new email coming from that account is not categorised this way? It doesn't seem you may change that behaviour via settings, maybe an add-in could help or JS API?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this issue. We are not stamping such a category in our code.

Can you check if :

- 1 You have any addins installed that are automatically stamping this category? It would be good to uninstall all addins too and see if problem is resolved.
- 2 Do you have any inbox rules setup that are auto categorizing mails for you. To check Inbox Rules, click on the settings gear menu on top right and go to Mail => Inbox Rules.